# Properties that update each other

Tags: c#, properties, circular-reference

So, in some C# code, I have something similar to the two properties:

```
private string _foo;
private string _bar;

public Foo
{
   get;
   set {
      _foo = value;
      Bar = _foo.Substring(3, 5);
   }
}

public Bar
{
   get;
   set {
      _bar = value;
      Foo = "XXX" + _bar;
   }
}
```

Question: Are C# properties subject to circular references/updates, like this example would seem to cause?

Comment: did you try this in a Console app and checkout?

Comment: Well, do you see an infinite loop when you run your program?

Comment: @PhilipHanson Maybe it's still running?  :-)

Comment: No; I have a problem where I was thinking of having two (related) properties...in fact, where one property is a subset of the other's information as above!  This is more of a conceptual problem at present than a concrete implementation.

Comment: If you would replace Bar = _foo.Substring(3, 5) to _bar = _foo.Substring(3, 5) or _bar = value.Substring(3, 5) should work without infinite loop

Comment: I would create a class with two properties and use an appropriate constructor. So instead of holding both strings here, i would encapsulate them in a separate class and hide this complexity.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: problem with that is, the 'actual implementation' that I'm anguishing about is part of an MVC app, and one of the properties has a text field in the appropriate view.  If this class were being encountered purely in code, I would do just that...of course, if I were doing that, the fields would be `private readonly _foo, _bar`, with only getters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the infinite loop by updating the hidden field directly, like this:

```
private string _foo;
private string _bar;

public string Foo
{
   get { return _foo; }
   set {
      _foo = value;
      _bar = _foo.Substring(3, 5);
   }
}

public string Bar
{
   get { return _bar; }
   set {
      _bar = value;
      _foo = "XXX" + _bar;
   }
}
```

This will bypass the other property's setter, which eliminates the loop.

**But**... this generally causes maintenance headaches later on. Personally, I'd try to find an alternative design.

Comment: I heartily agree on the alternate design; part of the problem is the fact that one of my properties is a fragment of the other, yet due to some other part of our system, updating the fragment can (and should, for integrity purposes) be used to update the superset.  **Lesson for Me**: prop-prop updating is not the correct tool for this job.

Comment: What about updating the fragment through a separate method, but allowing it to be accessed through a read-only property? Not sure if that is possible with your setup. Is it a requirement to update via property?

Comment: It is not a requirement to update via property. :)  I'll use that tactic with this bit of code.  Thanks for the great advice!

Comment: There _was_ a design problem in my snippet.  Where I had two properties that updated each other, each with their own hidden field, what I really only needed was one hidden field that each property updates in its own way.  The fragment's setter just pads the front of the data with stuff that fulfills the formatting; the full setter performs a full value set.  The getters just return what they need to (either, the fragment or the full value.)

Answer (score 2):

> Are C# properties subject to circular references/updates, like this example would seem to cause?

Yes. You have a nice, infinite loop here.

Comment: accepted Philip Hanson 's answer, even though you provided the direct answer.  Reason: he added an implementation that would circumvent the issue, though the design in question is suboptimal.

Answer (score 1):

Properties in C# are simple methods (getter and setter). You call one method from other method and vice versa. Result is completely expected.

Would this surprise you?

```
public void set_Foo(string value)
{
   set_Bar(value.Substring(3, 5));
}

public void set_Bar(string value)
{
   set_Foo("XXX" + value);
}
```

Call `set_Foo("XXX12345")` and.. you'll see the name of this site

Comment: I knew the get/sets were actually methods beneath the hood...wasn't sure if there was some terminating factor *also* hiding under the hood that would prevent my seeing Stack Overflow.  Now, I know that answers is a resounding **No**.

Comment: @AndrewGray exactly, compiler simply generates methods with names `get_` and `set_` and method body equal to property body. Nothing more

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the infinite loop, here's an alternative to Philip Hanson's answer: run the setter lines only when the value actually changes. Be nice; this is my first post/answer

```
private string _foo;
private string _bar;

public Foo
{
   get;
   set {
      if (_foo != value)
      {
         _foo = value;
         Bar = _foo.Substring(3, 5);
      }
   }
}

public Bar
{
   get;
   set {
      if (_bar != value)
      {
         _bar = value;
         Foo = "XXX" + _bar;
      }
   }
}
```